# Django throws 'Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.' error when user tries to log in

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

I am trying to log a user in order to display a webpage.I created my own login and signup forms and handle my own authentication for log in.I am using django's `login()` method.

Now I know because I am not using django login and authentication, so I need to create an additional field called `last_login` which I did.Here is my django model

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    username = models.EmailField(null=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

This signs up the user when the user hits /signup url.Below is the postgres table for the model.

```
   Column   |           Type           | Modifiers 
------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id         | integer                  | 
 username   | character varying(100)   | 
 password   | character varying(50)    | 
 last_login | timestamp with time zone |
```

But when the user tries to log in with their username and password (after visiting /login url), I get the below error

```
ERROR 2018-07-22 22:38:18,625 django.request Internal Server Error: /login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/Utora/kriktona/webhook/ui_server.py", line 94, in authenticate
    login(request, user.first())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 156, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 25, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 894, in _save_table
    raise ValueError("Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.")
ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

Here is the authentication code for login below

```
@csrf_exempt
def authenticate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_request = request.POST
        user = SignUp.objects.filter(username=user_request.get("username"))
        if user:
            password_db = str(user.values("password")[0]["password"])
            if password_db == user_request.get("password"):
                login(request, user.first())
                redirect("/home")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Failure")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failure")

    else:
        print("show login page")
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

I am not quite sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: You **must not do this**. It is horribly insecure to store passwords in plain text. Always use Django's authentication.

Comment: Not safe if you can get the user's password. 
Would suggest to encrypt data and do it as Django auth does:  **from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate** then use **user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)** after **login(request, user)**  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it easily by changing

```
user = SignUp.objects.filter(username=user_request.get("username"))
```

to

```
user = SignUp.objects.filter(username=user_request.get("username"), password=user_request.get("password"))
if user:
    return login(request, user)
```

However  you should strongly read this as contrib allready has all you need and also encrypts it and it's more secure than yours as people in comments said. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login